# How to play multiple songs together in sync?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, audio-player, opensl, android-music-player

I want to play 5 songs together without any miss sync. I've taken reference from the below link with use of NDK:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

I'm creating 5 instance for player and playing songs but on some devices songs are not played in sync when I just fire a play.

I would like to know what is the best way to achieve this so I can play multiple songs in sync.

Let me inform you the device having good configuration like 2gb+ RAM will play sounds in perfectly But in device having RAM of 1GB will not work always.

I've tried with MediaPlayer and Soundpool but not helps me. NDK implementation is far better.

Looking for best work around for this...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you should use [sound pool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)  here is an example how to use it:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-soundpool-example/

Comment: I have tried with Soundpool but result is not acceptable. Its more unsync compare to my current implementation.